# What are some of the most useful aliases and bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias

I just picked up some basic bash over at Codecademy today. I was curious what some commonly-used or personal favorite aliases and bash scripts are out there to put in my bash_profile document. Is there something you can't live without?

Comment: this is somewhat of a poll / opinionated question. google search and you will find tons of hits throughout the internet .

Answer (score 1):

Some basic aliases:

```
 - alias ls="ls --color=auto"
 - alias greg="grep --color=auto"
 - alias ll="ls -l"
 - alias la="ls -a"
 - alias wipe="rm -ri ./*"
```

And if your system doesn't recognize "poweroff"

```
 - alias poweroff="sudo shutdown -h now"
```

I would also recommend a shell script/cronjob to backup your home directory, and anything else important. A script with all of you iptables rules is also helpful. Finally, a script to generate good passwords encourages a secure system.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

`alias l="ls -l"
alias la="ls -la"
alias lsa="ls -a"
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias df="df -h"
alias ps="ps -ef"
alias info="pinfo -a"
alias man="pinfo -a -m"
alias top="htop"
alias tree="tree -N"
alias su="su -"
alias gk="gitk --all"`

The color settings for `ls` are defined in `LS_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score -1):

Use of general purpose aliases or 'use anywhere' scripts hampers productivity, so **I don't recommend them**. I've got >10 years of experience in AIX and Linux administration and I've never created my own aliases. I don't create my own universal scripts either, only scripts that help with a particular task on a particular environment.

Sooner or later you will reach the point where you have tens (or hundreds) of different systems, each with multiple accounts (your own, root, tomcat, etc) and possibly your co-workers sharing some accounts with you. With `bash` your best friend is Ctrl-R key, period. If you start to depend on `ll` to perform `ls -l` it would soon become a liability not an asset. Caring for the aliases would decrease your productivity instead of increasing it.